# Poco Release Version and LibVersion

Tags: poco

Is there a file which ties the libversion to the release number. The libversion is in a file in the release, but I can't find documentation to trace this back. Working with a version of Linux that has one libversion of Poco and a SDK that was released was a different libversion and I am trying to track down the releases. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured I go ahead and try to get and answer on Git Hub. There is no master file/database with the numbers , but it isn't super difficult to find. If you go to the tagged version (eg 1.11.0) and look at libversion - the number will be 81. Go back to tag version 1.6.1 and the libversion and the number is 31. I was able to create the database of the versions I needed based on trial and error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).